# Skeleton boilerplate wont load right when i separate the header main content and footer to different views?

Tags: css, codeigniter, skeleton-css-boilerplate

i am trying to load skeleton CSS from getskeleton.com in codeigniter, i am using a template system that i separate my header(opening html, links to CSS, the header of the page) in one view, the navigational bar in another view, the main content in a third view, a side bar in a forth view, and my footer and closing html in a fifth, i have tried appending them to a variable in the controller to load the view, also have tried using a template view to load each view, both systems work fine to load the views, the later is what i had before i started trying to use skeleton, it loaded the css fine, but nether one will load the skeleton css files. if i right out the layout in pure html as a whole doc all of it loads just fine, what am i doing wrong?

this is what i have in my views:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7 ]><html class="ie ie6" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7 ]><html class="ie ie7" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8 ]><html class="ie ie8" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if (gte IE 9)|!(IE)]><!--><html lang="en"> <!--<![endif]-->
<head>

<!-- Basic Page Needs
  ================================================== -->
<meta charset="utf-8">  
<title>The GroundScore Way</title>
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="author" content="John Fyffe">

<!-- Mobile Specific Metas
  ================================================== -->
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">

<!-- CSS
  ================================================== -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://gscore.webege.com/css/base.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://gscore.webege.com/css/skeleton.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://gscore.webege.com/css/layout.css">

<!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->

<!-- Favicons
================================================== -->
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/favicon.ico">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="images/apple-touch-icon.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="72x72" href="images/apple-touch-icon-72x72.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="114x114" href="images/apple-touch-icon-114x114.png">

</head>
<body>

<!-- Primary Page Layout
================================================== -->

<!-- Delete everything in this .container and get started on your own site! -->

<div class="container">

    <?php include_once("analyticstracking.php"); ?>

    <div id='header' class="sixteen columns">

        <img src="http://gscore.webege.com/imgs/gsbanner.jpeg"  alt=""/>

    </div>
```

this is the nav:

```
<div id='nav' class="four columns">

<?php 


for($i =0; $i >= 9; $i++)
{
    echo '<BR />';
}           


$keys[1]= array( 
            'home', 'about', 'members', 'news', 'blog', 'projects', 'portfolios', 'contact'
        );
$keys[2]= array(
            'login', 'signup'
        );
$keys[3]= array(
            'logout'

        );

foreach($keys[1] as $link)
{
    if($page != $link)
    {
        echo '<a href='.base_url("main/page/$link").'><img src="'.base_url("imgs/".$link."_0.png").'" /></a>';
        echo '<br/>';
    }
}

echo '<br/><br/>';

foreach($keys[2] as $link)
{
    if(!$this->session->userdata('is_logged_in'))
    {
        if($page != $link)
        {
            echo '<a href='.base_url("main/page/$link").'><img src="'.base_url("imgs/".$link."_0.png").'" /></a>';
            echo '<br/>';
        }
    }
}
```

this is the main content:

```
<div id='main' class="eight columns">
<?php 



    $page = $pd['results'];

    foreach($page as $row){

        $title = $row->title;

        $cnt_tl = $row->cnt_title1;

        $text1 = $row->text1;
        $text2 = $row->text2;

    }

    echo heading($title, 1);


    echo heading($cnt_tl, 2);
    echo '<BR />';
    echo '<p>'.$text1.'</p>';


?>

</div>
```

this is the side bar (i havnt developed it any trying to get the display right first):

```
<div id='side' class="four columns">
<p>this is the side bar</p>
</div>
```

and this is the footer:

```
<div id='footer' class="sixteen columns">

        <p>&copy;Copyright (c) 2012 ground-score.com. All rights reserved.</span> </P>

</div>

</div><!-- container -->


<!-- End Document
================================================== -->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: the server is down at the sec, my hosting companies end, they have been down a lot lately

Comment: i took the file that came with skeleton as an example turned it from .html to .php it would no longer load the css, with out changing it,

Comment: would it be that codeigniter only loads the first file but not the other two